# Java code conventions: Using 'default' as a variable name

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

I would like to use 'default' as a variable name. Is there a code convention (like class -> clazz) that suggests how I should name the variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually add a term that indicates for *what* it is the default. So I'd use `defaultName` or `defaultPermission` or possibly `defaultValue` (only if the meaning is clear for the context).

Comment: Well actually that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I have several entities that have a list of other entities (for example user has several address) and one of the list elements is the 'default' entity for the other entity.

I'm using dozer mapper to map the entities to DTOs (and to get the default something) and by using generics and a generic 'default' variable (instead of defaultAddress) I can do the mapping with just one custom converter (instead of writing a seperate custom converter for every entity).

But I guess defaultValue should do

Comment: @Sand: why not make it `defaultEntry`, `defaultEntity` or  `defaultSelection` depending on what *exactly* it is.

Comment: `defaultValue` is a good option in cases where you're dealing with primitives, too.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing: if it is a fixed value - a constant instead of a variable - make it final or even static final/public static final and keep it as class member instead of a local variable.  You should write constants upper case.

### Example

```
public class MyClass {

  public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "MyApplication";

  public String name;

  public MyClass() {
      this.name = DEFAULT_NAME;
  }

}
```

Comment: The name should be `DEFAULT_NAME`. The Sun Coding Convention says that multiple words should be separated with an underscore in constant names.

Comment: // , @tweber, this is actually the best answer, since it answers follow-up questions that the original asker might not think of.

Comment: @NathanBasanese - Thank you